# Capture traffic to/from a network node

Tags: linux, vpn, local-area-network, wireshark

I would like to capture all traffic to/from a network node. I don't know much about the network setup there, here's what I know:

The target node is a Linux server, which has no access to internet, only available through LAN. I can only access this server with Putty through VPN. As this VPN blocks all access to internet, I use a virtual machine to run the VPN client. So, in short: my physical computer -> virtual machine -> VPN -> target Linux server.

So, my question is: is it possible to use wireshark to capture traffic to/from this Linux server? I use a 64 bit Windows 8.1 host, and a 32 bit Windows XP virtual machine (I could also use a Windows 7 virtual machine, but the VPN is set up on the XP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login on the Linux server and use tcpdump in order to capture all traffic from/to relevant server. You can then use your captured dump in Wireshark for further analysis.

```
tcpdump -i <youInterface> -w dump.cap
```

Where:
-i : Interface to capture traffic from.
-w : Write captured traffic to file

On "yourInterface" you might want to add your tun/tap vpn adapter. For example:

```
tcpdump -i tun0 -w dump.cap
```

see [man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) of tcpdump for further details.